# How to insert some characters in mysql using pdo php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i want to insert text contain **\n** and **\"** but when i did it with pdo :

```
$received_data = file_get_contents("php://input");


$sth = $connect->prepare("UPDATE USERS SET botconfig='$received_data' WHERE id=1");
$result = $sth->execute();
```

the value of $received_data like this :

​​

> "start: \nsay "How i can help two three " \nsay
> "bla bla " \n

what i found in the mysql database :

```
start:  
say "How i can help two three "  
say "bla bla "
```

the **\n** and **/"** disappear from the database.

thanks for any help.

Comment: _"what i found in the mysql database"_ -  Are you saying that you have `echo` in the database? Or are you just trying to demonstrate that there are new lines? `\n` is an [escape character](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for a new line when inside a double quoted string.

Comment: **Warning!** You're code is _wide open_ to [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)! Read [how to prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) by using prepared statements with bound parameters instead of injecting variables directly into your queries. It's not just about security. If your data contains, for example, a single quote `'`, your query will break.

Comment: @M.Eriksson thanks for reply, i have input like this "start: \nsay /"How i can help two three /" \nsay "bla bla " \n", and i want to save it in the db without cut \n and /", i hope you understand my question

Comment: @M.Eriksson thank you so much, exactly what i mean, i need to keep **\n**, i don't want to replace it by new lines

Comment: You're preparing your statement, but doing so with an interpolated variable instead of a placeholder. This is just as vulnerable as just executing the query. Find a decent tutorial that covers prepared statements and update your code.

Comment: @M.Eriksson there is no software that I know which would render the escaped characters when outputting them. Everything I know renders on input. So the OP wants to prevent that.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular thanks, by the way i try all of them, using prepared statement but not working `$sth->execute([":received_data" => $received_data ])`